# Filter loop by 'price' with meta_query

Tags: php, loop, meta-query

I need to filter posts on a page based on max and min values for 'price' specified by the user.

I have the 'price' of the items registered in the database as 'longchar'.

The user inputs the 'price' it wants to filter in an `input type=text`.

The filtering part does not seem to work, nothing acutally happens.

For example, if the user wants to see all items that starts from 87€ and go up until 5.000,00€, the loop would look like:

```
$adsAll = array(
    'post_type'  => $postType,
    'meta_key' => $metaKey,
    'orderby' => $orderBy,
    'order' => $order,
    'posts_per_page' => $PostsPerPage,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'preco_anuncio',
        'value' => array('8700','500000'),
        'compare' => 'between',
        ),
    );
```

I get the value from the input, take all commas and dots out, then use the values to filter. I do that, because the values that are inserted in the database don't have commas nor dots.

Any idea where the problem might be?

When I use the same key, 'preco_anuncio' to filter from most expensive to less expensive, it works.

Comment: meta query argument is an array of arrays.

Comment: If I do that, it shows no result for the query, but I have items inside that 'range'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem.

I had to add `'type'    => 'numeric',` to my query.

**So the final code looks like:**

```
$adsAll = array(
    'post_type'  => $postType,
    'meta_key' => $metaKey,
    'orderby' => $orderBy,
    'order' => $order,
    'posts_per_page' => $PostsPerPage,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'preco_anuncio',
            'value' => array('8700','500000'),
            'compare' => 'between',
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            ),
        ),
    );
```